# What does Ollydbg termination code 0 and 1 means?

Tags: status, termination, ollydbg

I am debuggin an application. After loading i click f9 then program is getting terminated. Termination code at the bottom-left of ollydbg is showing status 1.

I want to know What does Ollydbg termination code 0 and 1 means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olly is just giving you the exit code of the program you are debugging.

Comment: It's specific to the program you are debugging. Normally a zero return value indicates success. A non-zero indicates some sort of error (i.e. a certain parameter hasn't been specified or is invalid).

Comment: @lifeaspanner is it possible to get these error code means. I am running a application on ollydbg showing termination code 1. I want to know reason for this so that i can fix the issue.

Comment: I don't know what the [exit code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) means, because I don't know what application you are debugging. I'm not sure if you're getting what Olly is telling you. Let me give you an example... If you wrote simple hello world style C program and in the last line of your program you wrote `return 0;`, Olly would say `Process terminated, exit code 0`. If you wrote `return 1;` Olly would say `Process terminated, exit code 1`. See? You're going to have to reverse the application to see why it's returning 1. What the return code means is specific to the application.

Comment: @lifesaspanner... thank for link and answer... I was thinking that code has special meaning which olly decide depending on error message application throws.. but the exit status code of a application is language and platform dependent...